# hex conversion in 64 bit python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

I'm trying to execute a sha1 length extension attack.

I'm stuck with the padding.

I have the length of the message, for example 257 bit, and, after converting in in hex is 0x101.

What I'd need is a 64 bit representation, so if the hex is `0x101', the correct format should be in python:

```
 '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01'
```

where each 8 bits are encoded in `\x` format.

Do you know how to implement this conversion in python3?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `0x101.to_bytes(8, "big")`? What are the input and output types of the operation you're looking for? `int` to `bytes`?

Comment: @MarkDickinson that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mkrieger1 you are right, this is the related question. I didn't found it because I didn't know how to formulate the problem properly.